# Create a forest mask from the Tropical Moist Forest dataset of JRC

Tags: google-earth-engine, forest-ecology, tmf

I'm building forest mask from different datasets to evaluate the product agreements. I would like to create one from the information contained in the Tropical Moist Forest dataset from the EU Joint research center but I don't find proper information on the bands available and how to merge them.

[image]

I took this table from their website as I don't find TMF in the dataset catalog. https://forobs.jrc.ec.europa.eu/TMF/data#gee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project includes  an annual change dataset: First, it is necessary to select the year of interest with the following code:

```js
var AnnualChangesYear = AnnualChanges.select('Dec2010');
```

Within this band the following values are availables:

```js
var PALETTEAnnualChanges = [
    rgb(0,90,0), // val 1. Undisturbed Tropical moist forest (TMF)  
    rgb(100,155,35), // val 2. Degraded TMF  
    rgb(255,135,15), // val 3. Deforested land  
    rgb(210,250,60), // val 4. Forest regrowth  
    rgb(0,140,190), // val 5. Permanent or seasonal Water  
    rgb(255,255,255), // val 6. Other land cover  
];
```

So forest can be defined as pixels were Forest is undisturb or forest has regrown:

```js
var ForestMask2021 = AnnualChanges.eq(1).or(AnnualChanges.eq(4)).selfMask()
```